# VBA defining Range with Cells() Error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

I am searching for a value and getting its Row with this, and I want to make a Range Variable with lRow and 2 (because it will always be 2), but it doesn't seem to work...

```
Dim lCol As Long

    lRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=Range("A1"), _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Row

lRow = lRow + 1
Dim newentry As Range
   Set newentry = Range(Cells(lRow, 2))
```

Here, `lRow = 3` is given as value...

Runtime error 1004: Method "Range" for object '_Global' failed

Comment: Try to better explain what you are trying to do? You are using the whole sheet instead of probably only the 2nd column for the Find method.

Comment: Drop the `Range`: `Set newentry = Cells(lRow, 2)`. Or `Set newentry = Range("B" & lRow)`.

Comment: Are you trying to find the last row in the worksheet?

Comment: From the linked duplicate: Range expects a string or TWO cells to define the range. With only one CELL remove the RANGE:

Comment: @VBasic2008 I am looking for the last row where data is put in, then add 1 to get the first, empty row  of sheet "Data"

Answer (score 0):

If you use Cells inside Range you need to add 2 cells even you want to select 1 cell only:

```
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1)).Select
```

your second cell is missing, that causes error